# How to remove data-wf-site and data-wf-page tags?

Tags: javascript, html, webflow

hey I am trying to remove data-wf-site and data-wf-page tags from my code, but the site just stops working properly, the dynamics just go off.
Is there a way I can remove the tags and keep the code working properly ?

Thank you :)

expecting to be able to remove those tags and still get the website to work properly with the animations

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are talking about an exported project. The practical answer is no since those are the hooks that Webflow javascript is tied to.